# Как правильно записать <> в strings.xml

Tags: xml

Кто-нибудь просветите меня как правильно записать к примеру  в strings.xml
Скажем:

```
<string name="value1"><h2></string>
```

Естественно это абсурд, так вот как правильно это сделать?
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как и в xml наверное. То есть так:

```
<string name="value1">&lt;h2&gt;</string>
```

Answer (score 4):

Знак "<" это последовательность четырех символов:  `&lt;`

Знак ">" это последовательность четырех символов:  `&gt;`

Знак одинарного апострофа это 6 символов:   `&apos;`

Знак двойного апострофа это 6 символов:   `&quot;`

Знак "&"  это 5 символов:   `&amp;`

Comment: И вообще все это называется XML character entities и в доках описано например https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML Можно также задать любой символ через числовую константу по его ASCII code (или UTF) например &lt; это &#60; https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_HTML

Answer (score 4):

Еще забыли упомянуть CDATA который чаще всего используется когда нужно воткнуть большой кусок текста без его трансляции как XML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean
и пример оттуда

```
<![CDATA[
Within this Character Data block I can
use double dashes as much as I want (along with <, &, ', and ")
*and* %MyParamEntity; will be expanded to the text
"Has been expanded" ... however, I can't use
the CEND sequence (if I need to use it I must escape one of the
brackets or the greater-than sign).
]]>
```

То есть в вашем случае это было бы

```
<string name="value1"><![CDATA[<h2>]]></string>
```